# Full stack Web application React.js,Node.js,express, mysql

Tags: mysql, image, types, backend

im a front end developer and want to become a full stack developer, right now i built an app using react.js, node.js and firebase for the database and is working fine. but now i want to build the same app using mysql as the database but i ran into a problem, this app is an ecommerce that has 7 different type of products. each of these products have items in it, for example one of the products is laminate floors, inside laminate floors theres different kind of floors, floor1, floor2, floor3, etc. this floors they have a title, description, price and images. i have the urls of the images of each product in an array, my problem is that i dont know how to store this array in a row in my sql.

for example the first row is going to be
title: floor1, price: 20, description: "blablabla", images:[multiple urls].
i havent found a solution to store an array of urls in images for the first product.

this might be a dumb question but i really appreciate if you can help me understand the logic, because in firebase i can store arrays of urls but in mysql i cannot.

Thank you

i tried creating a column images with the datatype JSON but i cannot send the array to be added

Comment: Don't store an array as a single value.  Create a separate table with a foreign key back to the parent table and store multiple rows in that separate table.

Comment: JSON _can_ (but _should_ is another question) be used to store multiple `url` objects, like `[{'url': 'www.test.com', 'name': 'example'}, { ... }]`, but you can also "normalize" your data, i.e. an `images` table, with a `url` column and `product_id` (or similar) column to link to the related record in another table. When you say *" cannot send the array to be added"*, what, specifically, do you mean? If you tried to save it as JSON and it failed, there's likely a reason why.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a multi-valued attribute (like multiple images for a given product), the proper relational database solution is to store a set of rows in a second table.

```
CREATE TABLE product_images (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  url TEXT NOT NULL,
  product_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (id)
);
```

By storing each image on its own row, you can just INSERT to add another image. To remove an image, just use DELETE for one row.

You can associate any number of images with one product, so you don't have to worry about how long an "array" is, or whether it's going to conflict with any length limits.

You can associate other attributes with each image, like if it is a thumbnail or if it's the preferred default image, crediting the source of the image, etc.

And so many other operations are easy instead of difficult! Counting images per product, searching for an image by name, and so on.